# Obtaining the primary key of a row currently being edited in GroceryCRUD

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm looking to obtain the primary key of a row that's currently being edited in GroceryCRUD. How can this be done? I am aiming to use the primary key in a query inside of a `if($state == 'edit' || $state == 'update' || $state == 'update_validation')` block.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered how to obtain this information.

```
$this->grocery_crud->getStateInfo()->primary_key;
```